# How do groups who reject the oral Torah explain David's election

Tags: king-david, oral-torah, heterodox

How can the oral law deniers explain the election of David ben Yishai when the Torah says "no Ammonite or Moabite shall enter into thd congregation of HaShem, none of their descendants, even to the 10th generation, forever"?

Comment: One common explanation is that the Pentateuch is dated to the 7th century BCE or later, which negates the issue. Another is that David's Moabite ancestry is fictitious. A third is that David never existed. I'm sure there are other explanations.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. That is true that these explanations are used by those who deny the Torah but my question is concerning the groups who deny the "Oral" Torah. Still, thank you for giving a answer.

Comment: You mean Karaites and such?

Comment: I was thinking this through - if Ruth could not have converted and David comes from her male descendants then he might be Jewish (if the male descendants married Jewish women) but he would not be from Judah.

Comment: @Harel13  Yes, for example  or the other "Torah only" self-interpreters

Comment: [Karaites seem to go by patrilineal descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karaite_Judaism#Who_is_a_Jew?), so for them David should be Jewish by virtue of descending from Boaz.

Comment: Perhaps illegitimate descent doesn't preclude kingship.